# Azure Dashboard Widget for Monetary Credit

Tags: azure, azureportal, azure-management, azure-dashboard

How can I add such a pie chart widget for monetary credit to my Azure Dashboard?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same question. I had a existing dashboard which did include this widget by default, but I could also not find a easy UI-way to add / update these type of widget.

My solution was to export my existing dashboard, look at the json file, edit the json file and reupload the Dashboard.json again.

See extract below from the part you need to add / update to the Dashboard.json file:

```json
  "<insert an unique id here> ⭐": {
     "position": {
      "x": 13, // The x-position on the dashboard ⭐
      "y": 10, // The y-position on the dashboard ⭐
      "colSpan": 4,
      "rowSpan": 2
    },
    "metadata": {
      "inputs": [
        {
          "name": "subscriptionId",
          "value": "<insert the subscription id> ⭐",
          "isOptional": true
        }
      ],
     "type": "Extension/Microsoft_Azure_Billing/PartType/BillingSubscriptionTile"
    }
  },
```

Upload modified .json file:

[image: upload dashboard.json]